# Make Text visible on grey rows in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, webkit

We basically have this html code for radio buttons in a table:

```
<div class="graytitle">Wie oft nutzen Sie WhatsApp?</div>
<ul class="pageitem">
    <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Sehr oft</span>
    <input name="frage10" type="radio" value="sehr oft" /></li>
    <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Mittelmäßig</span>
    <input name="frage10" type="radio" value="mittel" /></li>
    <li class="radiobutton"><span class="name">Ehr selten</span>
    <input name="frage10" type="radio" value="ehr selten" /></li>
</ul>
```

We want to grey out rows without making the text invisible, we have googled a lot but we couldn't find a solution. This is what we used:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.UmfrageForm.frage10.length; i++) {
document.UmfrageForm.frage10[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray"; }
```

It greys out all the rows, including the Text. We want the Text to be still visible after making the rows grey. How can we do that?

Disaster Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Either use a different background color, or change the text color when changing the background color.

Comment: Doesn't really help, the Text still disappears.

Comment: Is it possible to have a jsFiddle to understand better what happens?

Comment: Why are you using `<span>`s instead of `<label>`s? And would you mind [hosting your screenshots on imgur](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75491/133242) rather than puu.sh?

Comment: Pasted it in: http://jsfiddle.net/AzUN6/

Comment: I've used labels instead of spans and added a name to the labels. When changing the labels properties only, it worked. thanks for your help guys, especially Matt!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle: your stylesheet is positioning your span tags behind your input tags, that's why you don't see the span as soon as you remove the input transparency.

What you need to do is apply the background color to the span tags, not the input tags.

[Update] As @alicelieutier mentioned in the comments, if you only need to support recent browsers you could also choose to apply a semi-transparent background to the input:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.UmfrageForm.frage10.length; i++) {
  document.UmfrageForm.frage10[i].style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.7)";
}
```

Comment: you can also set a transparent gray using `rgba(0,0,0,0.7)` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've used the backgroundColor option on the spans, that I renamed to labels and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's possible, but you could add `id` attribute either to each of your `li` or `span` elements.

Let's say you give the following ids: `frage10_opt1`, `frage10_opt2`, `frage10_opt3`. You could then use the following code to change the text color:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.UmfrageForm.frage10.length; i++) {
    document.UmfrageForm.frage10[i].style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    document.getElementById("frage10_opt" + (i + 1)).style.color = "black";
}
```

Comment: @Michal - need to change the label color, not the input color.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yes indeed. I adjusted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. Do you want to 'gray out' the rows when a certain event fires or do you want them to always be 'grayed out'?

I think the problem with Michal's code is that you're running the loop for the form's radio elements, and your text is in a span tag before the element. You might try getting the radio element's parent (the li element) and setting the style colors:

```
for (var i = 0; i < document.UmfrageForm.frage10.length; i++) {
    var radioElm = document.UmfrageForm.frage10[i].parentNode;
    radioElm.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    radioElm.style.color = "black";
}
```

If you always want the radio buttons to be that certain color, I would suggest modifying the CSS classes of 'radio button' and 'name'